# a class for calculating the sum of factorials

Tags: java

```
case "ja":
          System.out.println("Ievadiet vardu");
          String x = input.next();                  
          n = x.length();    
          {         
              long fact;
              fact = 1;         
              for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                  fact *= i;
                  sum += fact;
              }       
          }
          break;
case "ne":
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);            
          System.out.println("Ievadiet ciparu");        
          n = in.nextInt();     
          if ( n < 0 ){
              System.out.println("Ciparam jabut pozitivam.");
          }     
          {         
               long fact;
               fact = 1;         
               for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                   fact *= i;
                   sum += fact;
               }     
          }
          break;
```

I'm trying to create a method that could calculate the sum of factorials so I can make this code shorter but I've made only simple methods and have no Idea how to get the method to output `sum` and how to properly call for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `getFactorialSum` method like this

```
// private means only this class can call the method.
private static long getFactorialSum(int n) {
  long fact = 1;
  long sum = 0;
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    fact *= i;
    sum += fact;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

And then you could call it like this

```
String x = input.next();                  
n = x.length();
long factorialSum = getFactorialSum(n);
```